# Resend data obtained with Stream to another PHP server

Tags: php, apache, exim

I have a mail server with EXIM responsible for receiving emails and sending their content to be read and treated by a PHP file. This content reading occurs through the command `fopen("php://stdin", "r")`, from that moment on I perform some actions using a library that allows extracting email from sender, subject, message content, attachments, etc.

My problem is that I will have to migrate this heavy part of email handling to another server, for infrastructure reasons. I'll just keep the main SMTP Server+PHP file that performs the `fopen`, and after that I must transfer all its content to another server on another hosting.

My main question is, is there any way to call the new PHP server which will be responsible for handling the email from what I got from the initial read file and sending the content as obtained with `php://stdin` in a single part? Similar to the first mode I received?

Comment: Read the data from your stdin, and then make an HTTP POST request to the other server. Either send the stream data as the raw body content (and then read it from `php://input` on the receiving end), or send it as a parameter in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, and then access it via $_POST.

Comment: @CBroe This can be done with a standard PHP cURL, correct?

Comment: Yes, PHP cURL should do fine for making this kind of request. Guzzle is also an option, and with a bit of fiddling with stream context options, you can even get `file_get_contents` to do it.